# Solving initial value problem that isn't easily separated

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We are supposed to write a program to solve the following initial value problem numerically using 4th order Runge-Kutta. That algorithm isn't a problem and I can post my solution when I finish.

The problem is, separating it out cleanly into something I can put into Runge-Kutta.

$$\exp(-x^\prime)=x^\prime-x+\exp(-t^3)$$

$$x(0)=1$$

Any ideas what type of ODE this is called? I feel more confident with CS skills and programming numerical methods than I do in math... so any insights into this problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an implicit ODE. One method to solve it would be to convert it into a differential-algebraic equation (DAE) and then use a method for solving DAEs. There are DAE solvers based on Runge-Kutta methods.

Another possibility is to do a nonlinear solve in the function for computing the right-hand side of the ODE. I mean the following. The standard form for ODE solvers is $x' = f(t,x)$ and if you implement a Runge-Kutta method, your program has to be able to evaluate the function $f$. For your equation, $f(t,x)$ is the solution of $e^{-y} = y - x + e^{-t^3}$, seen as an (algebraic) equation in $y$. If you know a method to solve this equation numerically, you can use that inside your Runge-Kutta program.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're prepared to tangle with Lambert's function (if $y=u+\exp(u)$, then $u=y-W(\exp(y))$), you won't be able to use Runge-Kutta on your ODE as it stands.